# different ui views in mobile and desktop

Tags: android, ios, laravel, user-interface, progressive-web-apps

I have a Laravel project and now I want to make PWA for it and use it on android an ios
I want to know can I have a completely different view of my website in mobile and tablets?
Thanks for answering

Comment: Although it is not 100% reliable (i.e. can be spoofed) you can see if some package like [Mobile-Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect) can be sufficient to serve your app's needs.